# What is the role of **in on**?

Tags: prepositions, usage

Below sentence is a conversation of Hermione in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secret.

> *Slytherin lead:* A gift from Draco's father.
>
> *Draco:* You see, Weasley, unlike some, my father can afford the best.
>
> *Hermione:* At least no one on the Gryffindor team had "**to buy their way in**".
>   They got **in on** pure talent.
>
> *Draco:* No one asked your opinion, you filthy little Mudblood.

What is the role of **in on**?

Does it mean the same as

> They got pure talent.

In addition to that what is the meaning of the phrase "***to buy their way in***"

I know conversation differs from the grammar. Is it possible to use the same in written form? It would be more helpful if someone explains this with examples.

**Note: Additional information has been added, and one more question is also raised.**

Comment: The two don't go together. _They got in_ (I don't know what they got into, you give no context), and _how they got in_ was _on pure talent_, meaning they got in because they had pure talent. If I would get into a country while walking, you could say _I got in on foot_. Your sentence could be rewritten as _They got in because of their talent_.

Comment: @oerkelens Additional information has been added

Comment: *They got in on pure talent* = *They got in based on (or: by means of) pure talent*

Comment: Then, what does "They got pure talent" mean? Does it mean the same?

Comment: _They got pure talent_ just means they have talent. It does **not** mean the same. The original sentence says they gor in (became part of the team) _because of their talent_. _Buying your way in_ means you get into something because you pay for it (as opposed to getting in because of your talent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To get in* is a phrasal verb meaning *to obtain access to.*

It does not mean the same as *to get*, which generally means *to acquire* an object, among several other meanings - although *to get in X* does mean *to acquire access to X*.

(Note that *to get X in Y* can also mean *to move X inside of Y*, with X defaulting to yourself if not specified.  It does not mean that here, though.)

A meaning of *X on Y* is the same as *X by Y* with an added implication that X happened because of Y.  Similar to saying *X based on Y*.

> She got in the club on her appearance = She got in the club by her appearance; her appearance caused her to get in the club = She got in the club based on her appearance.
>
> He got in school on his father's name = He got in school by his father's name; his father's name (and not his academic performance) caused him to get in the school...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added some more information to the question. Still, does your answer is same? If possible please answer my second question.

Answer (score 0):

not an expert on English but.... My inner feelings tell me **on** and **in** are not together in your sentence.

I mean **in** belongs to **got** => got in: was chosen for the team

and **on** belongs to **pure talent** => on pure talent: for their talent

*They was chosen for their talent not for fathers gift to team leaders*

Comment: You're right about **on** and **in** not being part of the same expression, but there are many other errors in your text, and that main point was covered by a *much* earlier answer, so I don't think this one serves much purpose.

Comment: what kind of errors?? show them please. and my english not that good i am not able to understand first answer

Comment: If you can't see errors in *They was chosen for their talent not for fathers gift to team leaders* perhaps you could post a question asking for help (but try to avoid presenting it as a "proofreading" question). If you can't understand @LawrenceC's answer you're *exactly* the kind of user we need to post comments asking for clarification. Native speakers don't always understand where and why learners have difficulty, so if *you* ask for clarification this may lead to improving edits to the answer - which will benefit other future visitors, not just you.